# RadWindow.Confirm Loses Theme when EventHandle Applied

Tags: c#, wpf

When my button is pressed, a RadWindow.Confirm appears. I would like to know what the user does if they click Ok or Close/Cancel. I implemented a `new EventHandler` But it reverts my theme and just shows "Telerik.Windows.Controls.DialogParameters" where the content is

Code that reverts the theme:

```
RadWindow.Confirm(new DialogParameters
{
    Content = "Please confirm activation of the selected schedule",
    Header = "Activation Prompt",
    Theme = new Windows8Theme()}, 
    new EventHandler<WindowClosedEventArgs>(OnConfirmClosed));
}
```

Code with theme

```
RadWindow.Confirm(new DialogParameters
{
    Content = "Please confirm activation of the selected schedule",
    Header = "Activation Prompt",
    Theme = new Windows8Theme()});
}
```

Implemented in MVVM

Answer (score 0):

But if you put Event within DialogParameters it works!

```
RadWindow.Confirm(new DialogParameters
{
    Content = "Please confirm activation of the selected schedule",
    Header = "Activation Prompt",
    Theme = new Windows8Theme(),
    Closed = OnConfirmClosed
})
```